# Using Over & Partition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a SQL table with monthly prices for products from different categories (e.g. fruits, vegetables, dairy).
I'd like to calculate a running monthly average for a specific category and for all the products in the same month, in the same query.

So combining:

```
Select date, avg(price) group by date where category = 'Fruit'

Select date, avg(price) group by date
```

Is that possible to do using OVER & Partition (or any other way for that matter)

Edit

- I am using MS SQL
- My data is monthly, so I don't need to extract month end dates -I can just group on date then I will get month end data
- As an example, if my table looks like this:

|Date| Item   | Category |Price  |
|Jan  |Banana | Fruit    | 10|
|Jan |Potato  | Veg      | 20 |

Then the output would be

Date | Fruit Avg | Overall Avg |
Jan | 10 | 15

Apologies in advance for mangling the tables, but that's for another thread.

Thanks

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. BTW, GROUP BY comes after WHERE.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

why you need over?

```
Select date, category , avg(price) group by date, category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Select extract(year from date)||extract(month from date) as month, 
       category, avg(price) as avg_price            
  from sales
 group by month, category
```

P.S. using alias `month` may not be allowed for some database systems, in that case replace month with `extract(year from date)||extract(month from date)` in the group by list. Also concatenation operator may differ, replace pipes( `||` ) with a plus sign ( `+` ) whenever such a situation is met.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per month *and* the data has multiple rows, then you need to aggregate:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as month, 
       avg(price) as avg_per_month,
       avg(avg(price)) over (order by date_trunc('month', date))
from t
where category = 'Fruit'
group by date_trunc('month', date)
 order by date_trunc('month', date);
```

If you only have one row per month, then you can do:

```
select date, price,
       avg(price) over (order by date)
from t
where category = 'Fruit'
order by date;
```